# Does the painting define a parking spot on a recently rebuilt sidewalk?

Tags: france, parking

My question is related to French law.

We had two parking spot in front of our house, painted with white lines, on the sidewalk. (there is enough space for both parked car and walkers).

Last year, my city removed the old macadam and put a new one, but did not added back the white lines that delimits the parking space.

We still park there even though the lines aren't present anymore.

Today, we received a parking ticket, saying we are not allowed to park there.

I called the city, and they told me that the line will be added soon. Calling them made things go faster, as they plan to come today to verify, and maybe do it while they are here.

So now, I wonder: Does the line (and/or absence of) define the law here, or the fact that there was a parking spot previously, and it's just the fact that the city worker hasn't put the lines here first, can allow me to refuse the parking ticket?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is any article mentionned on your ticket?

Comment: There was, which I followed. There is a grey area on where I was parked and the usage of "annoying parking" and "abusive parking". We contested the ticket, but still haven't received any responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We managed to get the ticket voided. Here's how:

After calling the city, I was able to reach out to the man responsible in painting the public parking spaces, and they told they could take a look and see if adding a parking place was possible. They came quickly and agreed that at least one place could be painted.

The place was painted about a week later.

I then took photo of my car at the same place (carefully having my number adress in the background to proove I was in the right place compared to the ticket), and showing that it was in a newly painted place.

I wrote a contestation letter, explaining that the place was painted before, wasn't when the agent wrote the ticket because the ground was rebuilt, but it was still on the city plan to keep that place, and the freshly painted place was a proof of that.

One could argue that the absence of paint when I was verbalized was enough to justify the ticket, and I agree with them, but we tried nonetheless.

We sent the letter along with the photo and we waited. It took a very long time (I'd say around 5 months) to get a response, and it was positive: they waived the ticket!

Our case was kind of special, so it might not apply to anyone, but it can help nonetheless :)